# Cognito get new token after updating user attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a question regarding Amazon Cognito.
What I want to achieve is to set default custom attribute for the user record.
Ideally it will be great if I could set it by default in user pool, for example `"custom:domain": "some name"`. But I can't find an example for this, or maybe set it up in `Pre sign-up` trigger with Lambda, but I didn't find examples for it also. What I did, when user authenticate I get the user attributes and set the required one with `updateAttributes` (I use `amazon-cognito-identity-js`). The downside of this approach that I faced, on first user login he gets the tokens first and only after that this custom attribute it set. So in first login this attribute is missed in token. What I want to ask what is the best approach of doing this kind of staff? And if my variant is appropriate, how could I update user token after changing the user attributes, so they appear in that token.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the new attributes in the tokens on token refresh. However, the SDK's do not provide a method to manually refresh the tokens. We will consider this as a feature request for our SDK's.
Tokens are typically valid for an hour and are automatically refreshed by the SDK when they have expired. So your user's would get tokens with new attributes at-least after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add a Pre token generation trigger that checks to see if the value is set, and if it isn't overrides it.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-token-generation-example-1  It would be set the first time the user gets the token if done this way.